# Spotfire: Custom Expressions How to learn?

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I am working with Spotfire and could not find a good documentation for custom expression. It is a bummer, since custom Expressions seem so mighty, but it has been a constant struggle by trial and error.

Comment: Did this help get you started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some great places to start. Also, the syntax is very SQL-ish, so if you are familiar with SQL Server or MySQL syntax especially it will help, though any SQL language would help.

### On The Web

[Overview](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_custom_expressions_overview.htm)

[Introduction](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_custom_expressions_introduction.htm)

[Basic Expressions](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_basic_custom_expressions.htm)

[Advanced Expressions](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_advanced_custom_expressions.htm)

[Details on Expressions](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_details_on_custom_expression.htm)

[Axes in Expressions](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_axes_in_expressions.htm)

[Some other overview...](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire-cloud-p/3.0.0/doc/html/sfire-cloud-p/GUID-3838B106-55D6-408D-A42F-6FB46CD17365.html)

[And lastly... some DEMO's](http://spotfire.tibco.com/demos)

---

### In Spotfire

Within Spotfire, when you attempt to insert a custom expression on a column, you can always browse all of the functions that can be used in a custom expression, and find help on any one you choose from within the processional client. Below is an image detailing this. Notice the yellow highlighted areas

[image: CustomExpression]

If you click the Help button on the bottom left, you will be taken to the most updated documentation:

[image: Help]